# I can't run sudo apt-get update in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, updates

```
sudo apt-get update


Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release [574 B]                                
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release [574 B]                                               
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release.gpg [801 B]                                                        
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release.gpg [801 B]                                                        
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/andrei-pozolotin/maven3/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                            
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease                                                                         
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security Release                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                   
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                         
Ign:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release.gpg                                                                
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/andrei-pozolotin/maven3/ubuntu artful Release                                                              
  404  Not Found
Hit:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                          
Hit:11 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x artful InRelease                                                                               
Ign:12 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                                                                      
Ign:13 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease      
Ign:15 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease    
Err:16 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Err:17 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Err:18 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Hit:14 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease                 
Reading package lists... Done                       
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/andrei-pozolotin/maven3/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons (stable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target DEP-11-icons (stable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
```

Comment: It seems you have issue with your internet connection. could you please confirm?

Comment: @Aditya .. or 17.10 is EOL !

Comment: 17.10 is not supported any more. After fixing errors you should seriously consider `18.04` upgrade.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.10 reached End Of Life on 19th July 2018. You should have upgraded to 18.04 long ago.

Edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and change

```
fr.archive.ubuntu.com
```

to

```
old-releases.ubuntu.com
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

You should upgrade to 18.04 as soon as possible after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was stuck too

Comment: Thank you i was stuck like op

Comment: this helpful, but the `sed` command at https://askubuntu.com/a/91821 is more helpful still